# Pagespeed Insights doesn't use gzip

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

PageSpeed Insights doesn't request files with gzip encodings, which leads to a wrong estimation of files sizes(makes them much bigger then they actually are).

I looked through bunch of similar questions and checked various answers, but nothing helped.

Then I estimated in PSI some of Google applications - google.com itself, youtube and others - and it seems like PSI doesn't recognize gzip on these sites either!

Check this out:
https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-www-youtube-com/1uxys155m3?use_original_url=true&form_factor=mobile

Find a little button "open performance card", it will show a visualization with files that are loaded from an application(youtube.com in this case).

Sizes on the map:

[image]

Actual sizes of biggest files in chrome devtools:

[image]

You can check it on any site.

So, if I'm correct it's a bug of PSI. Does anybody know a proper way to contact PSI team in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Treemap shows Resource Size, not Network size.

Network size is important as it correlates to download times.

But the uncompressed Resource size is **also important** since that impacts memory and processing time after it's downloaded.

For coverage checker in particular, this cannot really be done on a compressed file.

If you select ["Big request rows" in Network Panel settings](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference#request-rows) you'll see both the compressed and uncompressed sizes in that.

And there's a [separate audit which raises if gzip/br is not used](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/performance/uses-text-compression/), but in that example it passed - because Lighthouse does know about compression and does use it where possible:

[image: Lighthouse audit screenshot]

Comment: Could do with being documented to be honest! Have asked for that’s to be done.